# I have been working on a statistical model estimation using the R package optimx. Does anyone know how to get the Hessian matrix of optimx results?

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization, hessian

I have been working on a statistical model estimation using the R package optimx. My code works fine and I get all optimx summary results (parameter estimates, function values, convergence codes, etc.). However, I also need the Hessian matrix of these optimx results. I have unsuccessfully looked for help in the optimx documentation, R sites, and discussion forums. Can someone help me? Thank you in advance!!!

Here is an example (not a statistical model, but enough to show what I mean):

```
library(optimx) 

fr <- function(x) {
    ## Rosenbrock Banana function 
    x1 <- x[1] 
    x2 <- x[2] 
    100 * (x2 - x1 * x1)^2 + (1 - x1)^2 
    }

grr <- function(x) { 
    ## Gradient of ’fr’ 
    x1 <- x[1] 
    x2 <- x[2] 
    c(-400 * x1 * (x2 - x1 * x1) - 2 * (1 - x1), 200 * (x2 - x1 * x1)) 
    } 

ans1<-optimx(c(-1.2,1), fr, grr)
```

Comment: Please show the sample code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's all on the help page.  See `?optimx` under the "Value" heading (after `xtimes`).

> The attribute "details" to the returned answer object contains
>   information, if computed, on the gradient (ngatend) and Hessian matrix
>   (nhatend) at the supposed optimum, along with the eigenvalues of the
>   Hessian (hev), as well as the message, if any, returned by the
>   computation for each method, which is included for each row of the
>   details. If the returned object from optimx() is ans, this is accessed
>   via the construct attr(ans, "details")
>
> This object is a matrix based on a list so that if ans is the output
>   of optimx then attr(ans, "details")[1, ] gives the first row and
>   attr(ans,"details")["Nelder-Mead", ] gives the Nelder-Mead row. There
>   is one row for each method that has been successful or that has been
>   forcibly saved by save.failures=TRUE.

```
attr(ans1, "details")["Nelder-Mead", ]
$method
[1] "Nelder-Mead"

$ngatend
[1]  0.006260098 -0.002869164

$nhatend
          [,1]      [,2]
[1,]  802.4220 -400.1041
[2,] -400.1041  200.0000

$hev
[1] 1002.0216761    0.4003383

$message
[1] "none"
```

Get just the Hessians for both methods used (Nelder-Mead and BFGS)

```
attr(ans1, "details")[ ,"nhatend"]
$`Nelder-Mead`
          [,1]      [,2]
[1,]  802.4220 -400.1041
[2,] -400.1041  200.0000

$BFGS
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]  802 -400
[2,] -400  200
```

Get the Hessian for only the Nelder-Mead optimization:

```
attr(ans1, "details")["Nelder-Mead" ,"nhatend"]
[[1]]
          [,1]      [,2]
[1,]  802.4220 -400.1041
[2,] -400.1041  200.0000
```

Comment: I tried numDeriv which worked fine, but your suggestion is better. Thanks for your help, Frank!